# Proper way to add data to a table in postgreSQL using JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

This is my first post here, if my formatting is not correct/ hard to read, I will change it. Please let me know.

I have been playing with JDBC trying to add basic data to a database, using user input data. The user provides first and last name, email, and a user id is generated using the random function.

The database was created using postgreSQL. I'm trying to add to a table called accounts, which contains the following columns - user_id (integer), first_name (varchar(100)), last_name (varchar(100)), email (varchar(500)).

My program is able to connect to the database successfully, but it's not able to add data to the table.

in the following code, firstName, lastName, and eMail are all strings, while sID is an int.

```
state = conx.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO accounts VALUES ("+ sID +","+ firstName + "," + lastName + "," + eMail) + ")");

s.executeUpdate();
```

Normally, I'd hope the data would be added to the table so we can call it a day, but I'm getting an error.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "v" does not exist
  Position: 36
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:120)
    at Main.main(Main.java:49)
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "v" does not exist
  Position: 36
```

Comment: Your `PreparedStatement` variable is `state`. Why are you calling `s.executeUpdate()`? What is `s`?

Comment: Do not concatenate values in a SQL string. Use `?` parameters in the PreparedStatement. Otherwise your code will be vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: @WDS Using bind parms also improves performance and you don't need to worry about wrapping strings in quotes which, by the way, you forgot to do in the above example.

Answer (score 5):

Use `?` for parameters instead of concatenating their values. Also, you should name the columns in the `INSERT` statement. For example:

```
s = conx.prepareStatement(
  "INSERT INTO accounts (id, first_name, last_name, email) " +
  "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
  );
s.setInt(1, sID);
s.setString(2, firstName);
s.setString(3, lastName);
s.setString(4, email);
int affectedRows = s.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: This did the trick! It definitely keeps the code much more readable! Is there any reason you have the execute update statement being stored as an int?

Comment: Once the SQL statement is executed, the database tells you how many rows were affected (as an int). In this case it will be always `1`, but in the case of `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements this value can be of use. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()